# Is it possible to show toast over android system settings (API 29+)?

Tags: android, toast, android-version

Previously I had a toast that used

```
Handler().postDelayed(DELAY){
   // show toast 
}
```

to navigate the user to some place in android settings. From API 29 this toast doesn't appear anymore. If I press the home button before the DELAY is over, it shows without an issue over the android desktop.

1. **Was there some unannounced change that it is no longer possible to show toast over android settings since API 29?**
2. **Is it still possible to show the toast there somehow?**

Answer (score 1):

Toast working for me still, if you want to show toast inside thread use this:

```
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
     public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
```

But if this not work for you, however, you can use the custom toast message everywhere you want. first, create `CustomeToast` class:

```
   public class CustomToast {

       public void showMessage(Context context, String message){

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( 
           Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
           View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
           View layout = view.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root);

           TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
           text.setText(message);

           Toast toast = new Toast(context);
           toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
           toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           toast.setView(layout);
           toast.show();
    }
}
```

Then use everywhere you want:

```
 CustomToast customToast= new CustomToast();       
 customToast.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),"Hi !");
```